# How to change the size value string to number

Tags: javascript, string

Here's the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-5wr2jo

```js
const data = [
  {
    color: 'red',
    _1x: "0",
    _2x: "12",
    _3x: "0",
    _4x: "0",
    xxs: "0",
    xs: "0",
    s: "0",
    m: "0",
    l: "0",
    xl: "0"
  },
  {
    color: 'red',
    _1x: "0",
    _2x: "9",
    _3x: "0",
    _4x: "0",
    xxs: "0",
    xs: "0",
    s: "0",
    m: "0",
    l: "0",
    xl: "0"
  },
  {
    color: 'pink',
    _1x: "0",
    _2x: "0",
    _3x: "0",
    _4x: "0",
    xxs: "0",
    xs: "0",
    s: "0",
    m: "0",
    l: "0",
    xl: "12"
  }
];

const result1 = Object.values(
  data.reduce((acc, { color, size, ...rest }) => {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(color)) {
      acc[color] = {
        color,
        ...rest
      };
      return acc;
    }

    Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
      acc[color][key] = (acc[color][key] || 0) + rest[key];
    });

    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result1)
```

What I'm trying to do is to convert the size value string to number cause instead it will sum it based on the sizes it just merge the value. for example on size xxs there's two value `xxs: 12` & `xxs: 13` instead of `1213` it will be `25`.

What I just need to do is to convert the size value string to number.

Comment: Try `(+acc[color][key] || 0) + +rest[key]`

Comment: I hope you have correct logic to add the two sizes. You can use Number(xss) to change string to number

Comment: @Shubanker how'bout when adding a total field?

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like this:

```
 Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
             acc[color][key] = parseInt(acc[color][key] || 0) + parseInt(rest[key]);
           });
```

Instead of:

```
 Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
             acc[color][key] = (acc[color][key] || 0) + rest[key];
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isNaN()` and `Number()` function of JavaScript. You can get more idea from attached link.

[JavaScript Number isNaN() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan_number.asp)

[JavaScript Number() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)